# SharePoint 2010 profile activity feed with REST

Tags: ajax, sharepoint, rest, sharepoint-2010

I can access a decent amount of profile information using https://mysite/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList but I don't see any link to a user's "activity feed" in there.

I have found some mention of https://mysite/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx but all the documentation in there is rather cryptic, I've gotten used to using REST and would like to know if this data can be pulled out without having to use SOAP.

Where is the "activity feed" and is it possible for me to grab a user's feed with a REST call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up scraping a farm temaplate page for its information

```
https://DOMAIN/_layouts/activityfeed.aspx?consolidated=true
```

But more generally, some kind souls have put together a jQuery plugin called [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/), which allows for rather painless access to many of the SP web services. I would be happy to help anyone who stumbles across this question in the future.